# How to load gremlin format CSV file into AWS Neptune

Tags: java, csv, graph-databases, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have a Gremlin format CSV file. How to load it into a graph database (here it is AWS Neptune) in Java code? Thanks.

Comment: I believe the Neptune website has examples of how to load CSV files into Neptune. If you want a more generic approach to load arbitrary CSV data you may need to write a simple program that can read a CSV file and issue appropriate Gremlin calls.

Comment: Yes, the AWS website has examples. But it is by AWS REST API. However, in our case, we could not implement REST approach. So I'm seeking if there're some APIs in Java to load data into the graph database.

Comment: You will need to write a little code that parses the CSV files and issues the appropriate Gremlin commands (addV() , addE() etc.) I have some simple examples in my Book/Tutorial that may help if you look here you will find some code you could probably use as a start: https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/blob/master/sample-code/GraphFromCSV.java

Comment: This may also help you. http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#javagsclient

Comment: Here is a link to the code that goes with that section of the book - https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/blob/master/sample-code/RemoteClient.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the Neptune documentation has some sample Java code similar to the code I pointed you to in the comments above that uses `withRemote` to connect to a Neptune instance. Once you have the connection established you can issue Gremlin traversals from your Java code and can add vertices and edges as needed.

Hope this helps.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-java.html

Kelvin

Comment: The initial intention i post this question is because CSV graph is compatible in Neptune via CLI directly. So I wonder if there's a way to use JAVA API to do this instead of with CLI. But here the "withRemote" way works. Thank you Kevin :)

Comment: Good news. Could you please accept the answer so others can see it was answered. Many thanks!